# Exempting sunday from oracle sql script

Tags: sql, oracle

Kindly help me check the script below

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN to_char(sysdate - 1, 'DAY') = 'SUNDAY' THEN
          trunc(sysdate - 2)
       ELSE
          trunc(sysdate - 1)
       END AS day
  FROM dual
```

I wish to return 2 days if the condition in the case is true else to return previous day but the script keeps returning the previous day

Answer (score 3):

To remove all language-dependencies you can use `TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) - TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1, 'IW')` to count the number of days since the start of the iso-week (which is always on a Monday):

```sql
SELECT CASE TRUNC( SYSDATE - 1 ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE - 1, 'IW' )
       WHEN 6                                                 -- Sunday
       THEN TRUNC( SYSDATE - 2 )
       ELSE TRUNC( SYSDATE - 1 )
       END AS day 
FROM   DUAL
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=505a56e62a2afb1ce3d16767ee974ee1)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `TO_CHAR(sysdate-1,'DAY')` then result is padded with spaces. Try `SELECT '"'||TO_CHAR(sysdate-1,'DAY')||'"'` in order to see the effect.

Use [Format Model Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) `FM` and you should define also the language explicitly:

```
TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'fmDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') = 'SUNDAY'
```

or

```
TRIM(TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')) = 'SUNDAY'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i used

Answer (score 2):

Use `DY` -- it is always 3 characters:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN to_char(sysdate - 1, 'DY') = 'SUN' 
             THEN trunc(sysdate - 2)
             ELSE trunc(sysdate - 1)
        END) AS day
FROM dual;
```

To be formally correct, you should include an NLS parameter as the third argument (`'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'`) to be sure that the results are in English.